# R non-conformable arguments

Tags: r, loops, matrix-multiplication

My apologies for asking a question that has been asked a thousand times but I still don't seem to be able to solve my problem.

I am trying to run this double loop:

```
rho=matrix(0,12,1)

for (i in 1:k){
  for (j in 1:n-k){
    temp=((1/(sigma^2))*(1/(n-i)))*((as.matrix(vR)[j,]-mean)%*%(as.matrix(vR)[i+j,]-mean))
    rho[i,]=temp
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Error in (as.matrix(vR)[j, ] - mean) %*% (as.matrix(vR)[i + j, ] - mean) : 
>         non-conformable arguments

Also, my formula is:

```
(1/sigma^2) * (1/(t-k)) * sum[(vR(t)-mean)*(vR(t+k)-mean)]
```

the sum is "large sigma" going from t=1 to T-k

Is it possible to run it like I am doing?

Comment: Can you make this reproducible... so other people can run it?

Comment: Maybe you want `m[k, , drop = FALSE]` and `m[, k, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @cory I added some data and hope you can run it now.

Comment: @Frank I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are suggesting - I'm still pretty new to R.

Comment: If `m = matrix(1:4, 2)` then `m[1, ]` is not a matrix but `m[1, , drop=FALSE]` is. If you want to use matrix algebra, you'll probably want to pay attention to whether you're using matrices and what their dimensions are. Conformability refers to matching dimensions between two objects.

Comment: I think you get that error when you deliver a zero length argument as well.

Comment: Yeah, 42's diagnosis looks right to me. You could have tried investigating by typing `i` and `j` at the console after getting the error to see something was whack with your indices.

Comment: @Frank I tried to look at what you said but I still can't really make it work. I will investigate what you said later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Frank: That was how I came to realize that even solving a potential problem with non-conforming matrices was not really fixing the error. There was still "non-conformance". The %*% operator actually accepts two undimensioned vectors and "does the right thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a safer method for handling the "matrix-multiplication" of vectors, the `crossprod` function. Furthermore, I think your error may actually stem in large part from the operator precedence of the seq function, ":" in the inner loop index setup over the "-" function:

```
for (i in 1:k){
 for (j in 1:(n-k)){  # note inner parentheses, safer to always use with "("
temp=((1/(sigma^2))*(1/(n-i)))*crossprod(vR[j,]-mean,vR[i+j,]-mean)
rho[i,]=temp
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This solved my problem and my results looks like some good values. the paranthesis in the the loop was all it took. You just saved my evenin :)